# base64_decode adding strange characters

Tags: php, base64, decode, encode

I'm using base64_encode to use on a return URL string, but when I get to the page to decode it (using base64_decode) it's adding this to the end of the string:

-zh��

Here's the code which encodes the string:

```
$sess_refer = 'http://www.mysite.com/create-report.html?view=report&layout=reports&data=selection'

<input type="text" name="referrer" id="referrer" value="<?php echo base64_encode($sess_refer); ?>" />
```

Here's the code which decodes the string:

```
$referrer = JRequest::getVar('referrer');
$sess_refer = base64_decode($referrer);
```

Which outputs this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/create-report.html?view=report&layout=reports&data=selection-zh��
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you have not got some non unicode gremlins in the urls, if copied & pasted it can pickup some invisible junk sometimes from programs like ms word, try re-typing it out fro scratch? also have a look at mbstring?

Comment: The original string is being grabbed by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], so there shouldn't be any hidden characters etc. I'll look into the mbstring function :)

Comment: `zh` is a Chinese language code (like the en- in en-US locale)... it seems awfully coincidental that `zh` and a character outside the range of your encoding are magically showing up together.

Comment: I tested it with other urls and it wasn't always -zh that was showing up.. there were a couple others too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit too long for a comment, but if it doesn't help I'll remove this answer.

You can make `base64_encode()` data web-safe by applying the below trick. Without it, the `+` gets turned into a space and might mess up the encoding.

```
strtr(base64_encode($s), '+/', '-_');
```

To decode:

```
base64_decode(strtr($s, '-_', '+/'));
```

**Update**

Also, the `HTTP_REFERER` is sent by the browser, so it should be treated as user input and thus should be sanitized as a valid URL, before you `base64_encode()` it.

Comment: Got error like `
Warning: base64_decode() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given` @Jack

Comment: @Jatin the code in my answer doesn't pass 3 parameters, only 1

Comment: I am getting � character, how to remove this @Jack

Comment: @Jatin if this answer doesn't help you directly, i would suggest asking another question with more details.